# USB drive is not recognized

Tags: usb, fdisk, dmesg

I have a Transcend USB drive that is not recognized by the system (Debian Jessie 3.16-amd64). Let me explain:
When I connect it to the PC (Gnome) it makes the typical sound of when a drive is connected, but it does not allow me to mount it.

When I write to the console **fdisk -l**
the console returns me the hard drive partitions without recognizing the USB memory.

```
Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048   39063551   39061504  18,6G Linux swap
/dev/sda2  39063552 1953523711 1914460160 912,9G Linux filesystem
```

(Please do not laugh a lot about my partitioned.)

When I write **lsblk** I see this:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda 
├─sda1 swap         a03dfeb5-91f8-4ed5-9785-175ec9bd293b [SWAP]
└─sda2 ext4         fdc3f436-512b-471c-a1bd-6ff9caef4023 /
sr0
```

**But what gives me some hope is that when I write *lsusb*, the prompt give this answer (I only show the memory part):**

```
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 058f:1234 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
```

And when I write **dmesg** the console responds with:

```
[21187.450951] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[21187.581068] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=1234
[21187.581070] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[21187.581072] usb 1-6: Product: Mass Storage Device
[21187.581073] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
[21187.581616] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[21187.581854] scsi18 : usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[21188.580422] scsi 18:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[21188.580638] sd 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[21188.581348] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Can someone help me, give me a link to a similar problem, or give me some idea how to solve this?
I am not interested in the data that has inside the memory, I just want it to work again and to be able to use it again.

Comment: Does Windows recognize this stick? If it does, what partition table and file system does it have? If it has exfat and your Linux system does not have the driver installed, you'll need to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the filesystem on the USB drive aren't recognized or damaged (unformatted). As you don't care about the data, just re-format it and check it for badblocks with `mkfs.vfat -c /dev/sdg`. **This will destroy all the data on your USB disk**. Make sure to check it with dmesg you'll get the same `[sdg]` device created once you've plugged it in.

This will make it compatible with both Windows & Linux systems, as it will format it as fat32. You can make any fs supported by your distro with `mkfs -t ...` (see `man mkfs`).

Comment: here is the answer...

`root@Cyborg-PC ~# mkfs.vfat -c /dev/sdg   `

`mkfs.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)`

`/dev/sdg: No Medium found`

It's driving me crazy!!!

Comment: It;s seem like if it did't recognize the usb memory....

Comment: @k.Cyborg Then your flash drive is likely faulty. You have to replace it.

Comment: I kind of knew it from the begining...but I want a second opinion.
Thanks for answer me anyway and sorry for the late responds...I'm in Cuba and my Internet connection is limited.
Thanks